# Qt window partially blank after closing popup window

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, x11, enaml

We're having an issue in a Qt app where part of the window is occasionally blank/white after closing a popup window that was in front. Anecdotally, the blank section is always in diagonal stripes from the top of the window. The main window and the popup window are full screen.

I've attached an image. The partial painting is on the right side of the image, which is the top of the touchscreen (and the red box is just pasted on to hide the actual content for this post).

[image: partial painting example image]

We are using Enaml with PySide bindings for the gui app. I've tried to find a way to force a repaint or refresh of the window after the popup window is closed. The best I could come up with through Enaml was this (in the popup window definition).

```
closed ::
    deferred_call(container.request_relayout)
```

What is going on? What terms are used for this? I tried to search for it without success. Is it likely occurring in Qt, or at the os or windowing level (Ubuntu/X11), or somewhere else? That would significantly help me diagnose and fix/workaround, but ultimately I need to fix the issue. How can I avoid or correct this behavior?